# Is postWith switching my request's Content-Type?

Tags: rest, haskell, post, http-headers, wreq

No matter what value I enter as my request's "Content-Type", the outgoing request I send out seems to replace it with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The application I'm trying to hit expects "application/json". My code, basically, is below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wreq

...

submissionResources = ["https://widgets.example.com/v2/widgets/request"]

sendWidgetToEndpoint submissionResources workingToken key widgetArray = do
    let opts            = defaults & header "Content-Type"  .~ ["application/json"]
                                   & header "apikey"        .~ [key]
                                   & header "Authorization" .~ [workingToken]
        endPointURL     = head submissionResources 
        widgetId        = widgetArray !! 0
        numberOfWidgets = widgetArray !! 1
        widgetText      = widgetArray !! 2
    submissionResult <- postWith opts endPointURL [ "widgetId"     := widgetId
                                                  , "numWidgets"   := numberOfWidgets
                                                  , "widgetText"   := widgetText
                                                  ]
    return submissionResult
```

My problem is that I keep getting back `Status {statusCode = 415, statusMessage = "Unsupported Media Type"}` from this endpoint, and I'm confident this is because the request I'm sending appears to be overriding "Content-Type" in my header. I have tried using "application/json" and "text/plain" but the response I get back always indicates to me that all the headers I sent over look as expected except for Content-Type which invariably has become "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

How can I ensure wreq keeps 'Content-Type: application/json' in my requests header?

EDIT: I'm determining what headers were in my original request by what the API server tells me in its response back to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the last argument to `postWith` in your snippet is `[FormParam]`, and that type is what forces the Content-Type to be urlencoded.

To send JSON, send something of type `Value` or `Encoding` (from `Data.Aeson`).

```hs
import Data.Aeson (pairs, (.=))

  ...
  -- also remove the "Content-Type" field from opts
  submissionResult <- postWith opts endpointURL $ pairs
    ( "widgetId" .= widgetId <>
      "numWidgets" .= numberOfWidgets <>
      "widgetText" .= widgetText )
  ...
```

The Content-Type is set by the payload you pass to `postWith`, via the `Postable` instance. If you want to use yet another Content-Type header, define your own type with a `Postable` instance where you set an appropriate Content-Type. You can also choose to not set any Content-Type in the `Postable` instance, so you can set it via the options instead.